# formatting names in an index so that they appear in small caps

Tags: biblatex, indexing, small-caps, xindy

here is **my question** :

Can I modify the presentation of people's names in my index ?

**Informations about my document**

I am using the package **imakeidx** with **xindy**. I have two indexes, people's names in the principal one, and others in a second index called NC.

Peoples names get indexed in three ways :

- by the option *indexing=cite* of **biblatex**
- by the classical \index{Doe, John} command
- by some personal commands

The commands look this way :

```
\newcommand{\n}[2]{#1~\textsc{#2}\index{#2, #1}}
\newcommand{\nx}[1]{\textsc{#1}\index{#1}}
```

Everything is working fine in my index, except that the names appear in the index in this way : "Doe, John". I would like them to appear in this way : "DOE John" (DOE being in smallcaps like "\textsc{Doe} John" does)

If there is no first name (the reason why I have a \nx command), for example "Aristotle", I would like it to appear in small caps too.

Any idea how I could do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Check in the biblatex document `\DeclareIndexNameFormat` and friends.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer, here's what I did :

I was already having this command : `\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{{\indexnames{author}}{}}`. As I see it, it was for the author's names only to appear in the index, not the book titles.

So I added this one : `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index}{#1}{#3@\textsc{#1}, #3}{#5}{#7}}`

It works fine, except that :

1. single names (like "Plato") appear this way "PLATO, , 56" from Biblatex, and "PLATO, 56" from my indexing commands.

2. corporations names are still here.

I don't konw hove to solve those two problems.

Comment: As you didn't provide sensible code for testing I can't help you.

Comment: Compilable MWE with all index types included would be a great start for us, it's difficult to test ideas without the code. I could try to prepare a patch in Lua if there wouldn't be any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MWE works on my computer running under Ubuntu (it doesn't on the other one with Windows, but I guess that the problem comes from the installation and not the MWE) :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, ibidtracker=true, indexing=cite, citestyle=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=nc]

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{{\indexnames{author}}{}}
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index}{\textsc{#1}}{#3}{#5}{#7}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{BOOK,
author = {Doe, John},
title = {great book},
date = {2015-04-01},
}
@article{ARTICLE,
author = {{Group of Smart People}},
title = {great article},
journaltitle = {journal},
date = {2015-04-01},
}
@book{BOOK2,
author = {Plato},
title = {Gorgias},
date = {2015-04-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\n}[2]{#1~\textsc{#2}\index{\textsc{#2}, #1}}
\newcommand{\nx}[1]{\textsc{#1}\index{\textsc{#1}}}
\newcommand{\x}[1]{#1\index[nc]{#1}}
\newcommand{\y}[1]{\emph{#1}\index[nc]{#1@\emph{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

\nx{Plato} enjoyed \x{philosophy}

\y{logos}

\chapter{two}

\cite[35]{BOOK}

\chapter{three}

\n{John}{Doe}

\cite[33]{BOOK2}

\chapter{four}

\nx{Cicero}

\chapter{five}

\cite[35]{ARTICLE}

\printbibliography
\printindex
\printindex[nc]

\end{document}
```

**Notes :**

- I have edited my initial question because different questions were mixed in it, and I will ask them on separate questions.
- This works as well as there is a separate index for people's names. If they are mixed with common names, then they won't be sorted well, because of the command *\textsc* at the beginning. Then it would be necessary to add the @ in the index commands, but it becomes difficult for the *DelcareIndexNameFormat* command.